# How to run a Iphone backup with idevicebackup2?

Tags: command-line, backup, iphone, idevices

I try to do a backup of my Iphone SE iOS12.1.4. My Ubuntu version is Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.
I want to use the `idevicebackup` tool but I think I do something wrong because nothing happens.....

this is the command I try to use:

```
:~$ idevicebackup2 -u-d backup --full ~/backupiphone
```

but the only reaction what happens is that I get the -help information. 
What I am doing wrong?

[Terminal Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iqrV.png)

I also tried the code from this [man page](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Archiv/iPod/iPhone_und_iPod_touch/) but it has no different effect.

Thank you for your help and please be gentle, I am a new woman in the ubuntu tech world...

**UPDATE**
-I hava a Iphone SE Model A1723 with iOS12.1.4.
-Yes I can exchange pictures.

-I connected my Iphone with Ubuntu and used this comand:

```
sudo fdisk -l && lsusb && dmesg && usb-devices lsblk && sudo blkid
```

And get a hell of a lot information.... I think this are the three parts they are interesting...

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05ac:12a8 Apple, Inc. iPhone5/5C/5S/6
```

and

```
[  514.793618] ipheth 1-1.2:4.2: Apple iPhone USB Ethernet device attached
```

and

> T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=01 Cnt=02 Dev#=  5 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
>   D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  4
>   P:  Vendor=05ac ProdID=12a8 Rev=08.04
>   S:  Manufacturer=Apple Inc.
>   S:  Product=iPhone
>   S:  SerialNumber=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   C:  #Ifs= 3 Cfg#= 4 Atr=c0 MxPwr=500mA
>   I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=06(still) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=usbfs
>   I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=fe Prot=02 Driver=usbfs
>   I:  If#= 2 Alt= 1 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=fd Prot=01 Driver=ipheth

Comment: hi there! have you managed to connect your Iphone to your ubuntu before? (like to load pictures from it to your computer?) also what iphone model do you have exactly? also using the "format as code" in the question editor (`{}`) could you add the outputs of what you get in a terminal if you paste (plug the iphone in first) : `sudo fdisk -l && lsusb && dmesg && usb-devices lsblk && sudo blkid` ? to paste to a terminal you need to add the "Shift" key : (ctrl+Shift+V) to copy (the result) from a terminal, you need to add the "Shift" key : (ctrl+Shift+C)

Answer (score 1):

The *syntax* in your command is a little bit wrong.
Your command is: `:~$ idevicebackup2 -u-d backup --full ~/backupiphone`

You are missing a space in your command between `-u` and `-d`.
So the right command would be:

```
:~$ idevicebackup2 -u -d backup --full ~/backupiphone
```

Then you get the expected output.
For more information about the `idevicebackup2` command see [here](https://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=1&topic=idevicebackup2).

Comment: Include your device's UDID after `-u`, which you can retrieve by `ideviceinfo`. You don't need `-d` which is the debug option for it to run. `~/backupiphone` can be any directory of your choice.